# No module named 'pyspark.conf'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I tried to run [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) the below library:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSessio
```

in Jupyter Notebook the error came out that `"No module named 'pyspark.conf".`

I followed the steps of installing [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) one by one but unfortunately, I faced that error.

I installed [findspark](/questions/tagged/findspark) by [anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda) navigater and also by `conda install -c conda-forge findspark`  , then Spark zip file from the official website and placed it in `C:\bigdata` path, and after that [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) in anaconda navigator and also by `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark`.

Here are my Environment variables:

```
HADOOP_HOME  C:\bigdata\spark3
SPARK_HOME   C:\bigdata\spark3
Path         C:\bigdata\spark3\bin
```

By the way, the below [findspark](/questions/tagged/findspark)library works properly

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

Although, still face the same error. Please let me know if you have any ideas, thanks.